# CSS - Styling two child divs if they follow each other

Tags: jquery, css, sass, drupal, css-selectors

I have two child divs that need to have less margin when following each other, but i cant figure out how to do it.

I can't change `field_item`, yet I can use jQuery as a last resort.

e.g.

```
<body>
    <div class="field_item">
        <div class="narrow video-block">narrow video-block</div>
    </div>
    <div class="field_item">
        <div class="narrow video-block">narrow video-block</div>
    </div>
<body>
```

The margin between these two field_item divs is 3rem, but I would like it to be 1rem when two `narrow` child containers follow each other:

is this possible?

[image: narrow video block]

Some pseudo code:

```
IF field_item.narrow is followed by .field_item.wide 
THEN margin-bottom is 5rem.

ELSE IF field_item.narrow is followed by .field_item.narrow
THEN margin-bottom is 1rem.
```

Comment: When you say 'follow each other' do you mean horizontal alignment? And if so what width are you expecting? A 50/50 split?

Comment: the classes .narrow follow each other in the DOM,and field_item is just a container. So when `field_item.narrow` is follow by a `field_item.narrow`. Does this make more sense?

Comment: Does the [Adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) suite your task? Used like this `.field_item { margin-top: 3rem; } .field_item:first { margin-top: 0; } .field_item + .field_item { margin-top: 1rem; }`

Comment: And by the way: in your markup you nested the class `.narrow` inside the element with class `.field_item` so the example selector you posted will never match `field_item.narrow`

Comment: Pseudo code thanks martin. Also Martin, no it wouldn't work in regards to your first comment because the second .narrow div isn't an adjacent sibling. thanks but we solved it with Jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the :not([:last-of-type](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#last-of-type-pseudo)) CSS selector to apply the margin to all `.field_item` elements except the last one in a group.

```
.field_item:not(:last-of-type) {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

**Update based on additional information:**

Based on the updates, I'd suggest rethinking the approach. It's a little difficult to understand the context of the question given you've only provided minimal information specific to your example. But maybe you could look at releveling your DOM structure.

If that's not possible you could use jQuery similar to the following to traverse the DOM and add an additional class wherever there are two `.field_item.narrow` items following each other.

```
$(".field_item").each(function(index) {
  var thisItem = $(this).children(".video-block").first();
  var nextItem = $(this).next(".field_item").children(".video-block").first();
    
  if (thisItem.hasClass("narrow") && nextItem.hasClass("narrow")) {
    $(this).addClass("marginSmall");
  }
});
```

```
.marginSmall {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

Comment: This wont work because it needs to change the margin of the .narrow class only if a .narrow class is following it.

Comment: I added some pseudo code to my question to explain more what i am looking for

Comment: @SweetChillyPhilly I've updated the answer to reflect the extra information.